# AttributeError: 'ResultPage' object has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am creating this personal assistant for my coursework and using KIVY for making the UI for it.
I have two screens and one of them has a variable called `query`. When i try to access it for another screen, it gives `AttributeError: 'ResultPage' object has no attribute 'query'` error. I have tried every help on stackoverflow and none of them works.

**Code**:-

```
class CommandPage(Gridlayout):
... 
...
    def input_button(self, instance): # creating the button that when pressed updates the label
        self.query = "You Said {}".format(self.command()) # making the query
        if self.query == "You Said None":
            self.update_info('Please input a command')
        else:
            self.update_info(self.query) # updating the label
            Clock.schedule_once(self.change_screen, 10) 
            #waits for 10 frames and calls the change screen function.
...
class ResultPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.testLabel = Label(text=self.query) 
        self.add_widget(self.testLabel)
```

Its the query that I want to access from the CommandPage and show it as a label in the ResultPage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shared property, you can define `query`  in the App class. Then access it in python as `App.get_running_app().query` and in kv as `app.query`